# Decimal number in string-data-type with large amount of decimals always interpreted as large integer (regional decimal separator issue)

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:** I'm receiving data for my Excel application from an API in JSON format. For this matter I'm receiving numerical values as a string, as everything sent in JSON naturally is a text format - and so does VBA also interpret it.  As I'm located in Denmark, using a different decimal separator than the native on in Excel (my Danish version utilizes `,` as separator rather than `.`).

**Case:**
This is causing quite a bit of trouble as Excel interprets this as a thousand-separator when converting the string to a number.

Searching for answers I've found that the best solution, normally, is to convert the string to double when using VBA, utilizing `CDbl(string to convert to number)`.

This usually is the case, but in my case I'm receiving a number with a lot of decimals such as: "`9.300000190734863`".

When doing a `CDbl("9.300000190734863")` this results in a very large integer: `9,30000019073486E+15`

Also, I don't think utilizing a `replace()` approach is feasible in my case as I might also have data that uses both decimal- and thousand separators at the same time, making my results prone to replacement errors.

However, inserting the string value directly into a cell within Excel converts the number correctly to `9,30000019073486` in my case.

**Question:** Can it be right that there's no way to mimic, or tap into, this functionality that Excel obviously is using when inserting the string into a cell?

I've searched for quite some time now, and I haven't found any solution other than the obvious: inserting the value into a cell. The problem here is that it's giving me some performance overhead which I would rather avoid.

Comment: Why not just replace periods with commas before casting the string to a double?

Comment: @JoshEller sorry I completely forgot to include the reasoning for that part in my question and was in fact editing it as you wrote. Please see above :)

Comment: Well, it seems like you just want to swap the places of periods and commas. Just do it in 3 steps; replace commas with "X" (or some other value that won't appear in your data), replace periods with commas, then replace "X" with periods

Comment: @JoshEller ......... how on earth didnt I think of that. I've even used this approach for other parts of the same application... Please post an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: Posted it, no problem haha, sometimes we get so ingrained in an issue that we miss the obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap the positions of the periods and commas in your input prior to casting as a double, in three steps:

1. Replace commas with 'X' (or some other value that won't appear in your data)
2. Replace periods with commas
3. Replace 'X' with periods

Comment: Thank you! For reference to others: In my case i ended up doing the following (to be 100% certain that my swap-sign wont appear anywhere else): `Replace(Replace(Replace(string, ".", "||"), ",", ""), "||" , ",")` swapping the dot decimal-separator with `||` , removing eventual thousand-separators (no need for them in my case) and then replacing `||` with my regional decimal-separator `,` .